# ListFragment - when adapter data change list positions are overridden and not added

Tags: android, list, listview, android-fragments, fragment

I'm using SherlockListFragment(whichis the same as ListFragment) for displaying sms conversation list

Here is the code

```
   public static class TitlesFragment extends SherlockListFragment 
{
     static ConversationAdapter adapter;
     static List<String>    msgList;
     static Activity        activity;
     static ListView listView;

       @Override
       public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        DataGetters dataGetters = new DataGetters();
        activity = getActivity();
        msgList = dataGetters.getCONVERSATIONS(activity.getApplicationContext());

       adapter = new ConversationAdapter(activity, msgList);
       setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Code above prints all current sms conversations
like this:

[image]

I'm refreshing adapter from code below by calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); witch is called when new sms is received

```
public class ReceiverClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    Thread.sleep(2000);

return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


      TitlesFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

But fallowing code overides existing list view items insted of adding new list item position like this:

[image]

When i activity is recreated i get what i want but only then: example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely incorrectly modifying the List that the ListAdapter is attached to.

Comment: Yeah great man was sitting on this for last 2 days and didnt notice that i dont modify my list! thanks ! would kiss and hug you so much if i could! I wasted so much time on this alredy ech:(

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was not me not modifiy adpater list with new position

Here is the code that neded to be added

```
  msgList= dataGetters.getCONVERSATIONS(activity.getApplicationContext());

  ConversationAdapter.msgList = msgList;

  TitlesFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Solved thanks to Mark Nguyen